# Unix and FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd

My final goal is to write the program which can run on the Unix OS. I know that there are many Unix versions, and don't know exactly for now which one I need to support. I cannot install any Unix OS right now. The only thing I can do is to use free OS which is close to Unix as much as possible. Is FreeBSD a good choice for this? I know that there is also OpenBSD, possibly something else.

Additional information:
The programing language is C++, I am using GCC, with some portable libraries: Boost and wxWidgets.

Comment: what program are you writing? shell scripts? C program?

Comment: Unix is not an OS, it's a family of OS.  You're doing most of the right work by using gcc.

Comment: @Andrew, the term UNIX is overloaded, and so his confusion is understandable... UNIX formerly was an operating system and now it is an open standard for operating systems as well as a family of operating system (namely those that comply with the spec).

Comment: @Michael, Fair enough, but there hasn't been only one unix in over 30 years, so I think it's reasonable to look at this issue from today's standpoint.  Today, most of the unix-based operating systems people use are actually a flavor of linux, so when people refer to unix, they're generally using a generic description of an operating system that is derived from the original unix.

Comment: @Andrew, that is true... but unfortunately out-dated literature is still widely available on the interwebs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenBSD, FreeBSD, DragonFlyBSD, NetBSD, Open Solaris, etc. are all open and free Unix operating systems, you cannot really get closer than that.

To circumvent the installation restriction consider virtualization with a tool like Sun's [Virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: The BSDs aren't certified Unix, but Open Solaris is.

Comment: Thank you, this is information I am looking for. My restriction is that the program is not open source. I need to provide binaries compatible with target OS. So, I need to install one of these OS and build the program there, is this correct?

Comment: @Alex: Binary compatibility will be tough. Learn more details about the target system. Your FreeBSD x86 binaries won't run well on Solaris running on Sparc system.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what your program does, what language it is written in etc. you can write portable code on any platform. For example, I routinely port one of my applications written in C++ from Windows, where I develop it, to Linux, with one minor change (I remove ODBC support). So the choice of OS to do the development on is not critical - consciously writing portable code is.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard. It's portable API supported by most of Unix like operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Single UNIX Specification](http://www.unix.org/single_unix_specification/). If you make only the assumptions given in the man pages provided by the OpenGroup in its Single UNIX Specification, then your code should work on all UNIX-compliant OSs.

If you use my [development/coding search engine](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/references/development-search), it is heavily biased in favor of sources from the Single UNIX Specification, and clicking on "Single UNIX Specification" will limit the search to that source. As long as you restrict yourself to the guarantees made by the spec, then it should work on all UNIX variants.

I should also point out that if you restrict yourself even further to using only features provided by the ISO C++ standard, by the Boost C++ libraries, and by WxWidgets, then you should be able to target not only all variants of UNIX, but also Windows as well. However, if you only need to target UNIX, then any of the system interfaces in the Single UNIX Specification as specified therein should be safe to use.

In terms of development environment, I would recommend that you install a copy of [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/) in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), since setting up a working development environment on that particular distribution of Linux is as simple as a single invocation of `sudo apt-get install`, and Linux is de-facto compliant with UNIX. The single command `sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config g++ automake autoconf cmake doxygen libboost1.40-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev` is sufficient to get a fully working C++ development environment on Ubuntu with WxWidgets and the Boost C++ Libraries installed.

Answer (score 2):

what programs are you writing and what language are you using? Whether you use FreeBSD or Solaris etc, you can write fairly portable code using C++/Python/Perl etc. These programming languages can work in different platforms and i don't think you will have major problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of systems mentioned above have (limited) support for running linux binaries. You can try to build and distribute a linux binary. If you build it on something like RHEL4 most of them would support necessary ABI to run the program.

For example flashplugin on most BSD's is actually a linux-flashplugin.